# how to SUM a column by different condition then group by date

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I tried to sum values of a column (subtotal) into different columns(total, rejected, actual) that differentiate by its condition of a column (state).

Actual Table (ode_orders)

| Delivery Date | Subtotal | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2/2021 | 150.00 | Delivery Completed |
| 2/2/2021 | 45.00 | Rejected by business |
| 2/2/2021 | 45.00 | Delivery Completed |
| 2/2/2021 | 87.00 | Rejected by business |
| 3/2/2021 | 45.00 | Delivery Completed |
| 3/2/2021 | 70.00 | Delivery Completed |

I want it to make it as new table as:

| Delivery Date | Total Sales | Rejected | Actual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2/2021 | 150 | 0 | 150 |
| 2/2/2021 | 177 | 132 | 45 |
| 3/2/2021 | 155 | 0 | 155 |

**I tried using this query:**

```
SELECT  delivery_date, 
  SUM(subtotal) AS TotalSale,
  SUM(subtotal) WHERE state NOT LIKE %Completed% AS TotalSale
FROM ode_orders
GROUP BY delivery_date;
```

**The results**

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE state NOT LIKE %Completed% AS TotalSale
FROM ode_orders
GROUP BY deliver' at line 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
 SELECT delivery_date, SUM(subtotal) AS TotalSale,
 SUM(case when State='Rejected by business' then subtotal else 0 end) as Rejected ,
SUM(case when State='Delivery Completed' then subtotal else 0 end) as actual 
 from table_name group by delivery_date
```

Comment: Thank you so muc!! Another question is how to add total count of the orders by date? like we already got the total amount of actual, but it is better if we also count of how many of the total order. For example, RM150 for total of 10 orders.

Comment: just count(*) as well with the answered query btw it if helps mark as accepted

Comment: I already got for the total count of all. But when I count by 'rejected' condition, it count all row, I want to exclude the 'completed' condition instead. @zaynul

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
,(totalSales-Rejected) Actual
from
  (
  select deliveryDate 
  ,sum(subTotal) totalSales 
  ,isnull((
  select sum(subTotal)  from ode_orders sa where sa.deliveryDate=a.deliveryDate and 
  [state]='Rejected by business'
  ),0) Rejected
  from ode_orders a
  group by deliveryDate
) mt
```